# Spring Boot фильтр загружаемых бинов

Tags: java, spring

Не работает фильтр загрузки бинов.
Что здесь можно поправить?
`ExcludePackageTypeFilter` реализован корректно.
После работы `ExcludePackageTypeFilter` он еще раз добавляет бины.

Application:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import ru.cft.aml.lists.configuration.ExcludePackageTypeFilter;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "ru")
@ComponentScan(
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
        type = FilterType.CUSTOM, 
        classes = {ExcludePackageTypeFilter.class}
    ),
    basePackages = {"ru"}
)
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

ExcludePackageTypeFilter:

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReader;
import org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReaderFactory;
import org.springframework.core.type.filter.TypeFilter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExcludePackageTypeFilter implements TypeFilter, EnvironmentAware {
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public boolean match(@NotNull MetadataReader metadataReader, @NotNull MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) {
        List<String> ignoredClassPaths = getIgnoredClassPaths(env);

        for (String path : ignoredClassPaths) {
            if (!ignoredClassPaths.isEmpty()
                    && metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName().startsWith(path)) {
                System.out.println("не загружаем bean: " + metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private List<String> getIgnoredClassPaths(Environment env) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        //....

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(@NotNull Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }
}
```